# Como faço para que uma data no Python se repita consecutivamente

Tags: python, pyautogui

Criei um código de programação automática no Instagram com Pyautogui.

Alguém sabe dizer como eu faço para após ele preencher a data inicial, siga uma sequencia de 30 até dias.

**Ex.: 12.05.2022,13.05.2022,...,12.06.2022**

Que coloque data inicial, siga o código abaixo e depois volte novamente com a data em sequência.

```
pi.click(x=994, y=546)#Clicar na data
pi.write('12.05.2022')#Data inicial
pi.press('Enter')
pi.hotkey('TAB')
pi.write('10')
pi.hotkey('TAB')
pi.write('00')
pi.click(x=1217, y=687)#Clicar em programa
time.sleep(11)
```

Comment: Eu sou contrário a esse tipo automação do Instagram pelo PyAutoGUI, sou favorável do uso da API do Instagram. Mas antes de inicializar a automação de interface crie uma lista com as datas e itere pela lista realizando a automação. Veja o exemplo https://ideone.com/e4BbbT

Answer (score -2):

No python, para trabalhar com datas você pode ter dois objetos distintos.
O primeiro é o objeto data. É uma variável com as características de data.
Guarda as informações do ano, mês, dia, hora e etc.
Com esse objeto é possível fazer cálculos, adicionar ou diminuir dias por exemplo.
E para utilizar a data como texto pode-se utilizar a função .strtime que transforma um objeto data para string.

Abaixo segue um código de sugestão:

```
import datetime

data_atual = datetime.date.today()                                 # cria o objeto data com a data atual do sistema.

data_atual_formatada = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')  # String da data atual.

data_futura = data_atual + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
data_futura_formatada = data_futura.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

print(data_futura_formatada)
```

Mais informações na documentação oficial:
https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).